# Can you change your eye shape in Animal Crossing:New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I want to know if you can change your character's eye shape.

Answer (score 4):

No, your eye shape depends on what you say to Rover on the train to the new town.

Have a look [here](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Face_Styles_Guide#Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf).